# Mixing Retina and non retina assets in openGL ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, retina-display

I would like to upgrade my 3D application with some high res assets, for iPhone 4.

I can't update the whole graphic content of my app. I want to mix images in high and low resolution.
All my application is rendered with OpenGL

The most part of my app is based on billboard sprites, so I can change the scale factor of my OpenGL view but I will have to scale all my low res sprites and update their positions.
Do you have another way to do this by changing as little code as possible?

Comment: Why does the scale factor of the OpenGL ES layer alter the coordinates you supply for the positions of your geometry? OpenGL should have its own coordinate space, independent of the pixel size of your display layer.  In my application, no change in the rendering code is needed to switch between Retina display and non-Retina display devices.

Comment: I want to use low and high resolution sprites. So I can scale high resolution sprite to 0.5 or scale low res sprites to 2.
If I scale high resolution sprites (with glScalef) I have a loss of quality.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I set all sizes and positions for 320x480 screen. And when running on retina device and using x2 texture I multiply its dimensions x0.5 after loading it (for example texture has 100 pixels width, but width value will be 50).